# How do I configure apache for a custom directory?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

Trying to configure apache2 to load example.com/forum/ from a different document root, relative to the site root. Forums are installed somewhere else on the server.

Is there a directory alias command? I've found the `alias` configuration entry for apache, but had no luck.

Basically, I want example.com to have the same directory its always had, but example.com/forum/ to be hosted somewhere else, on the same server.

I tagged this question with mod_rewrite because I thought maybe it would be the key, here.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Alias` is the right way, unless you have some subtlety that you didn't reveal in your question.

```
 # http.conf
 Alias /forum /usr/lib/bbs/  # or whatever
```

The job of `Alias` is to take the abstract URL coming into your system and map it to a concrete filesystem path. Once it has done that, the request is no longer an URL but a path. If there is no `Alias` or similar directive handling that URL, then it will get mapped to a conrete path via `DocumentRoot`.

If this isn't working, you have to debug it further. Are you getting errors when you access `/forum`? Look in the error log.

Comment: P.S. This is *extremely* common. Maybe users running Apache have some applications set up with locations outside of the document root, such as webmail, etc.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I was having trouble interpreting the documentation on alias. I will be sure to pass this along to anyone I work with.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends of what you want. You can "hardlink" with real path and it works (so you were right to think it could work with mod_rewrite).

Quick sample (that works on my production domains) to make an internal change (I add a subdirectory):

```
 RewriteRule  (.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mysubfolder%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [QSA,L]
```

So you can easily do something like:

```
 RewriteRule  ^/forum/(.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mysubfolder%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [QSA,L]
```

And my suggestion would be that if you plan to have more rewrite rules, keep everything homogeneous, i.e.: keep on using **only** rewrite rules, so use my suggestion above. This way you'll not get a bad mix of `Alias`, `RewriteRule`s and so on. For nice and clean stuff: keep everything homogeneous.

Comment: This is nonsense. `Alias` and `RewriteRule` do different things, both of which are appropriate in different stages of URL processing and which occur in the same server configuration. `Alias` maps a URL to a directory (and does not recurse: the result of `Alias` is not re-injected for re-processing). It is the right tool for redirecting top-level URL's to various application areas implemented on a server.  If you do not use `Alias` but only `RewriteRule`, then instead of a bad mix of the two, you can get a bad mix of `RewriteRule`-s.

Comment: Never use both arrays and lists in a program. Keep it homogeneous so that there isn't a bad mix. Also, don't use integers in a program that has floating point numbers and vice versa. Use only functions or only macros and stick to one paradigm: e.g. if there is functional programming, do not use objects. Cleanliness and homogeneity are the goal; getting the job done is just a welcome side effect.

Comment: Your first comment was enough, thank you for your suggestion. But if you do `Alias /forum /usr/lib/bbs/`, please, oh please tell me that in a RewriteRule, something like `RewriteRule (.*) /forum` will **never ever** be changed to `/usr/lib/bbs/`.

Comment: Otherwise, I stay on my position: using Alias and RewriteRules **may** lead to maintenance problems. Simple example: on some Linux distribs, you do aliases in the root file (**`httpd.conf`**) and RewriteRules in the **vhost** files. A developer makes a copy paste of the vhost file and guess what? It doesn't work. After 1-2 hours of searching he finally finds that this ----- developer has used aliases in the **`httpd.conf`** folder.

Comment: I'm not clever and I always try to do simple things. So, maybe you think that the whole world can do what you suggest, but from my point of view **and my experience** you should try, **whenever you can**, to put things that concerns one website at the same place. Btw I know you can use Alias in a vhost environment, but in practice, it's often done in the `httpd.conf` file.